# Getting error while creating JPA producer endpoint

Tags: java, jpa, apache-camel

I am new to Camel. I am writing a camel route for following scenario

1. Pick XML file from a location
2. Validate the XML file against XSD
3. Persist the XML data into DB

And i wrote like this

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
           JaxbDataFormat jaxb = new JaxbDataFormat();
           JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(Book.class);
           jaxb.setContext(ctx);

           from("file:data/source?noop=true").to("validator:books.xsd")
                                         .to("file:data/destination").split()
                                         .tokenizeXML("book").unmarshal(jaxb)
                                         .to("jpa:com.labs.Book");
}
```

And My XML file is :

```
<book>
           <author>Kishore</author>
           <title>The Second Book</title>
           <genre>Fiction</genre>
</book>
```

And my XSD is :

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="book">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="author" nillable="false"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="title" nillable="false"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="genre" nillable="false" fixed="{Fiction,Bio}"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And i have JAXB model for the XML. And i have pesristence.xml file also. But i am getting an exception like below, when i am trying to execute my application

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
1168  camel  WARN   [main] openjpa.Enhance - Unenhanced classes were detected even though the enhancer has ran. Ensure that the EntityManagerFactory is created prior to creating any Entities.    
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateProducerException: Failed to create Producer for endpoint: Endpoint[jpa://com.labs.Book]. Reason: <openjpa-2.3.0-r422266:1540826 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: This configuration disallows runtime optimization, but the following listed types were not enhanced at build time or at class load time with a javaagent: "
com.labs.Book".
           at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doGetProducer(ProducerCache.java:409)
           at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.acquireProducer(ProducerCache.java:123)
           at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.doStart(SendProcessor.java:202)
           at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:74)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:59)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:103)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:89)
           at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.doStart(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:79)
           at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:74)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:59)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:103)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:89)
           at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.doStart(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:1154)
           at org.apache.camel.support.ChildServiceSupport.start(ChildServiceSupport.java:41)
           at org.apache.camel.support.ChildServiceSupport.start(ChildServiceSupport.java:28)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:74)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:59)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:103)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:89)
           at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.doStart(DefaultChannel.java:153)
           at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:74)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:59)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:103)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:61)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:103)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:89)
           at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doStart(MulticastProcessor.java:993)
           at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:74)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:59)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:103)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:61)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:103)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:89)
           at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doStart(MulticastProcessor.java:993)
           at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:74)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:59)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:103)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:89)
          at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.doStart(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:79)
           at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:74)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:59)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:103)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:89)
           at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.doStart(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:1154)
           at org.apache.camel.support.ChildServiceSupport.start(ChildServiceSupport.java:41)
           at org.apache.camel.support.ChildServiceSupport.start(ChildServiceSupport.java:28)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:74)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:59)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:103)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:89)
           at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.doStart(DefaultChannel.java:153)
           at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:74)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:59)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:103)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:61)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:103)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:89)
           at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doStart(MulticastProcessor.java:993)
           at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:74)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:59)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:103)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:89)
           at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.doStart(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:79)
           at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:74)
           at org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.startChildService(RouteService.java:334)
           at org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:158)
           at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWarmUpRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:2263)
           at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.safelyStartRouteServices(DefaultCamelContext.java:2193)
           at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:1981)
           at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:1851)
           at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:1683)
           at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
           at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:1651)
           at com.labs.App.main(App.java:36)
Caused by: <openjpa-2.3.0-r422266:1540826 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: This configuration disallows runtime optimization, but the following listed types were not enhanced at build time or at class load time with a javaagent: "
com.labs.Book".
           at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.ManagedClassSubclasser.prepareUnenhancedClasses(ManagedClassSubclasser.java:115)
           at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.loadPersistentTypes(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:312)
           at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.initializeBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:236)
           at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:212)
           at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:155)
           at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:226)
           at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:153)
           at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:59)
           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
           at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.invokeProxyMethod(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376)
           at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean$ManagedEntityManagerFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:519)
           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.createEntityManager(Unknown Source)
           at org.apache.camel.component.jpa.JpaEndpoint.createEntityManager(JpaEndpoint.java:284)
           at org.apache.camel.component.jpa.JpaProducer.<init>(JpaProducer.java:44)
           at org.apache.camel.component.jpa.JpaEndpoint.createProducer(JpaEndpoint.java:106)
           at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doGetProducer(ProducerCache.java:405)
           ... 82 more
```

Thanks for your time and i appreciate your help. And if possible could you please refer some links to Camel JPA examples, where JPA Component is used as Producer.

Comment: I think i gave all the details required. Please let me know if you need further information. And please let me know if this is the correct approach or not ?

Answer (score 0):

From what the error message tells, and from what DuckDuckGo's search results shows, you are missing a part in your configuration and you have *weaved* the class com.labs.Book.

I don't know OpenJPA, but [this link](https://openjpa.apache.org/entity-enhancement.html) should provide you more information.

- for runtime, you need to enable javaagent
- for compile time, you need to enable maven/ant/whatever build configuration and tell maven to weave your class com.labs.Book.